# XPath: select node that contains normalized text, excluding ancestor nodes

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I'm looking for a performant, generic query to select "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." similar to how a simple CMD+C would copy the text.

It seems that I need to use the `textContent`, but my XPath is also selecting the ancestors (up to body), rather than just the first (few) ancestors. How can I limit the scope?

---

example `node.textContent`

```
"

    The
    quick brown fox
    jumped over the


    lazy dog.

"
```

---

Run Code Snippet → Full Page → Follow instruction

```html
<div id='dont-select-this' style='text-align:center'>
  <div id='dont-select-this-but-it-would-be-cool-if-you-could' style='background:lightgreen;'>
    <div id='select-this-one'>
      <p>
        <span>The</span>
        <em>quick brown fox</em>
        <span>jumped over the</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        lazy<span> </span><b>dog.</b>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>open chrome devtools → console</div>
  <div>change frame (see below)</div>
  <div>type <code>$x('//*[contains(., "quick brown fox")]')</code></div>
  <hr>
  <img alt='select chrome devtools frame' height=300 src='https://i.imgur.com/L1MhCY8.png'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[normalize-space() = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.']
```

selects only the two `div` elements with the following `@id` values,

```
dont-select-this-but-it-would-be-cool-if-you-could
select-this-one
```

as requested.

---

If you actually want to exclude the `div` element with an `id` value of `dont-select-this-but-it-would-be-cool-if-you-could` (despite its name) and *only* select the deepest element with the noted string value, then:

1. Add an additional predicate to the above XPath.
2. Change `div` to `*`.

Altogether:

```
//*[         normalize-space() = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' ]
   [not(.//*[normalize-space() = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' ])]
```

This selects only the `div` with an `id` attribute value of `select-this-one`.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way that doesn't rely on the only two selections being `<div>`s, but that they're direct ancestors, sorry about that..

Comment: So then substitute `*` for `div` in the XPath.

Comment: Incorrect.  `//*[normalize-space() = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.']` does not select `body` or `html` because those have ***string values*** that include strings from additional text nodes.

Comment: `$x("//*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')]")`

Comment: That would only happen if your HTML didn't include the additional elements that your posted code includes:  `<div>open chrome devtools → console</div>` etc.

Comment: I don't do chat because it doesn't help future readers.    If you cannot express yourself adequately in your question, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with this

```
//*[         contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.') ]
   [not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.') ])]
```

---

```
$x("//*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')][not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.') ])]")
```